# Wrong input Tensor when using .pb file

Tags: android, tensorflow, keras, protocol-buffers

I used Keras and TensorFlow to convert a MobileNet model to a .pb file, which I'd like to use in Android. The serialization apperantly worked fine and when I'm visualizing the .pb file in TensorBoard it shows a 4D input shape of (?, ?, ?, 3) which I guess is fine as I want to feed images in the format of (1, 224, 224, 3).
However after loading the model, converting a desired bitmap into that format and feeding it to TensorFlow via the TensorFlowInferenceInterface I get the following error:

```
"IllegalArgumentException: buffer with 150528 elements is not compatible with a Tensor with shape [1, 224, 224, 1]"
```

**150528** is exactly **1*224*224*3** so the size of the bitmap should be fine. But why is the Tensor of shape 1, 224, 224, 1 and how can I change that?

Comment: Found the error myself: because I was relying on an example that used an MNIST trained model I forgot to change the dim parameter of the feed function from 1 to 3.